# Cannot connect to MySQL database on different server

Tags: mysql

I have web server (SII) and MySQL server (phpMyAdmin) on one machine(IP 10.93.4.36) where everything is working fine.

When I try, with PHP,  to retrieve some data from database running on other SQL server(10.93.30.182)(in the same network) I get the error:

```
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it (errorNo 2002).
```

Do you know what could be the problem? Maybe MySQL config file should be edited?

Comment: Check your rights of your mysql user, if the mysql user only has access from localhost you cannot connect from another server.

Comment: you better uninstall your skype or any apps that corrucpting your port in apache or in mysql..or try to change the wamp port

Comment: MySQL is on Port 3306 by default. There usually aren't any conflicts in port usage with anything there.
Did you check that your Firewall allows inbound acces to MySQL on Port 3306? You can completely disable the FW for a short time to test if this is the reason for your Problems.

Comment: I got the information that distant database is running on SQL server. Can I have conflict with ports?

Comment: I need to use other function in PHP to connect to SQL server. I'll post here if it's working.